# Clickonce and postbackevent

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation, clickonce

I have a WPF project and a post build event which copy files from a folder outside of the solution into the output directory.

I want to publish my application with Clickonce publish.  The only problem is that the copied files are not included in the publish or the manifest.

I tried using MageUI.exe , msbuild /target:publish from the visual studio cmd and even tried to change the project file by hand including a beforepublishevent but none of that worked.

I am open to suggestions, but what I want is to take the output folder and make the installer install the output files.  (e.g. install the .net 4 framework and visual c++ runtime libs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want them in the solution, but you do want them in ClickOnce then the only possibility is to use an external tool to create the ClickOnce manifests as you can't add non-project files to the ClickOnce output in Visual Studio.

There are two options I know of:

1. Use MageUI to manage your ClickOnce manifests. You can add additional files to your application in Mage.
2. You could use some software that I created and sell called ClickOnceMore (www.clickoncemore.net). ClickOnceMore will allow you to add all the files in one directory to your ClickOnce manifests by adding a single folder include. You can also then control which sub folder on the client they get deployed to. It was designed to make scenarios like this simple. You can download a free trial on the web site.

I hope it helps. Apologies for the marketing plug, but I do think ClickOnceMore can solve your problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the files through a post-build event, why don't you include them inside the project, and mark Copy to Output Directory = Copy if Newer?
If they are DLLs, you can add them as reference instead.

There are other options to create installers such as WiX+SharpSetup. It's much more flexible, but also more complicated, and takes more time to create simple installers.

Comment: Yeah, that idea is was my last option.. it's a lot of files..
Is it possible to Create in the soulotion a folder with all the extra files but make it to copy to the output dir instead to output/newFolder dir ?

Comment: You can try using the Move MSBuild task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595163.aspx. I'm not sure it will include the files in the installer though.

Comment: I don't think you can change where they are output to during the copy. If you put them all in sub folder they will be moved to sub folder in the debug/release folder. I have added a new answer below with another possible workaround for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you , i will try again using mageUI...
i will check your installer also